# Python Pool.map() - locally works, on server fails

Tags: python, windows, server, multiprocessing, arcpy

I've researched many pool.map on SO and still can't seem to find anything that hints at my issue.

I have `if __name__ == '__main__'` in every .py file. I have `freeze_support()` in each .py that contains `import multiprocessing`, I am still at a loss for what is happening. I've moved the `freeze_support()` around in my code with the same unsuccessful results.

Script A calls Script B, Script B calls Script C (where the multiprocessing happens). Locally this scenario works perfectly, but when I load it to a Windows Server 2008 machine, strange things start happening.

On the server I can see the first iterable printed to the interpreter, but it then jumps back to Script B and keeps processing. There are 51 other items in the list for Script C.

Script B Code:

```
if not arcpy.Exists(MergedDataFC):
    ScriptC.intersect_main(input1, input2) 

if not arcpy.Exists(MergedDataSHP):
    shpList = arcpy.ListFields(*.shp) # output of multiprocess
    # Merge all shapefiles into single shapefile
    # Being executed before the multiprocess finishes all 52 items
```

Script C Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def intersect_main(input1,input2):      
try: 
    mp.freeze_support()
    # Create a list of states for input1 polygons  
    log.log("Creating Polygon State list...")  
    fldList = arcpy.ListFields(input1) 
    flds = [fld.name for fld in fldList]
    idList = []  
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input1, flds) as cursor:  
        for row in cursor:  
            idSTATE = row[flds.index("STATE")]
            idList.append(idSTATE)  

    idList = set(idList)
    log.log("There are " + str(len(idList)) + " States (polygons) to process.")  

    log.log("Sending to pool")  
    # declare number of cores to use, use 1 less than the max  
    cpuNum = mp.cpu_count() -1

    # Create the pool object  
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=cpuNum)  

    # Fire off list to worker function.  
    # res is a list that is created with what ever the worker function is returning
    log.log ("Entering intersectWork")  
    res = pool.map((intersectWork(input1, input2, idSTATE)),idList)
    pool.close()  
    pool.join()  

    # If an error has occurred report it  
    if False in res:  
        log.log ("A worker failed!")  
        log.log (strftime('[%H:%M:%S]', localtime()))
        raise Exception
    else:
        log.log("Finished multiprocessing!")
        log.log (strftime('[%H:%M:%S]', localtime()))  
except Exception, e:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]   
    # Geoprocessor threw an error 
    log.log("An error occurred on line " + str(tb.tb_lineno)) 
    log.log (str(e))

def intersectWork(input1,input2, idSTATE):  
try:  
    if idSTATE == None:
        query = "STATE IS NULL"
        idSTATE = 'pr'
    else:
        query = "STATE = '" + idSTATE + "'"

    DEMOlayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input1,"input1_" + idSTATE)

    log.log (query)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(DEMOlayer,"NEW_SELECTION",query)  

    # Do the Intersect  
    outFC = r'C:/EclipseWorkspace' + '/INTER_' + idSTATE.upper() + '.shp'
    strIntersect = str(DEMOlayer) + ";" + str(input2)
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis(strIntersect, outFC, "ALL", "", "LINE")
    return True  
except:  
    # Some error occurred so return False 
    log.log(arcpy.GetMessage(2))
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    intersect_main(input1, input2)
```

**Edit**

All the data on the server is stored locally, no across network processing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the full path to the data wasn't being properly passed into the pool.map() on the server, from previous modules. I had to add all the files paths under the import statements. Not very elegant looking, but it's working.